# Calculation is not working with custom Cell Rendering with AJAX in Handsontable

Tags: javascript, php, handsontable

In my table(Handsontable) I have four columns **Cars**, **A**, **B** and **C**.
Data for **Cars** and **A** columns are loaded from MySQL database. (like **[PHP Demo](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/blob/master/demo/php.html)**).

Data of Column **B** is populated from MySQL database via AJAX depending on the value of **Cars**. The code is as follows:

```
{type: { renderer : function (instance, TD, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
                var cr,prc;
                cr = instance.getDataAtCell(row, 0);
                prc = instance.getDataAtCell(row, 1);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "php/act-go-t.php",
                    data: {cars: cr, price: prc}, 
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (res) {
                        if (res.result[0].tax === null) {
                            TD.innerHTML = '0.000';
                            }
                            else {
                            TD.innerHTML = res.result[0].tax;
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                        TD.innerHTML = '0.000';
                        }
                    });                 
                }}}
```

The C column is the **SUM** of **A** and **B** and the code is:

```
{type : { renderer : function (instance, TD, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                    Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
                    var a,b;
                    a = instance.getDataAtCell(row, 1);
                    b = instance.getDataAtCell(row, 2);                     
                    TD.innerHTML = +a + +b;
                }}}
```

The problem is although the value is loaded in **B** but the addition is not working. If I set the type of **B** column to numeric(`{type: numeric}`) except the AJAX, the addition is working fine.

Result with AJAX:

> ```
> +----------+------+-------+--------------+
> | Cars     |   A  |    B  |            C | 
> +----------+------+-------+--------------+
> | Nissan   |   20 |    10 |          20  |  
> | Honda    |    5 |     6 |           5  |    
> +----------+------+-------+--------------+
> ```

Result without AJAX:

> ```
> +----------+------+-------+-------------+
> | Cars     |   A  |    B  |           C |
> +----------+------+-------+-------------+
> | Nissan   |   20 |    10 |         30  |  
> | Honda    |    5 |     6 |          11 |    -
> +----------+------+-------+-------------+
> ```

Can anybody please tell me if I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `TD.innerHTML = res.result[0].tax;` is only for displaying data, however it not inserts data into datamap.

You may try to set a `id` for that cell and get the value of that by jquery and summing them up. So the codes will look something like that:

```
{type: { renderer : function (instance, TD, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {

                var cr,prc;
                cr = instance.getDataAtCell(row, 0);
                prc = instance.getDataAtCell(row, 1);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "php/act-go-t.php",
                    data: {cars: cr, price: prc}, 
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (res) {
                        if (res.result[0].tax === null) {
                            TD.innerHTML = '0.000';                                
                            }
                            else {
                            TD.innerHTML = res.result[0].tax;                                
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                        TD.innerHTML = '0.000';                            
                        }
                    });  
                arguments[5] = TD.innerHTML;
                TD.id = row+'_'+col;
                Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);

                }}}
```

And

```
{type : { renderer : function (instance, TD, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                    Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
                    var a,b;
                    a = $('#'+row+'_1').text();
                    b = $('#'+row+'_2').text();                     
                    TD.innerHTML = +a + +b;
                }}}
```

Comment: Still I am facing some problem. Most probably the html value not fetch by `$('#'+row+'_1').text();`

Comment: I just change the code slightly. I pass the html of the TD to cell value. `arguments[5] = TD.innerHTML;`